# Getting all users from Active Directory PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the following code to access the list of users in my AD, however on the line where I add the users to my combobox I get a null reference exception.

```
PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomainip");
UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);

foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll())
{
    if (result.DisplayName != null)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(result.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I replaced the combobox with a `Console.WriteLine(result.DisplayName)` and it works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not 100% sure if that's the problem - but `PrincipalSearcher` really returns a list of `Principal` objects.

So if - for whatever reason - your searcher would return something that's *not* a `UserPrincipal`, then your object `result` would be null - not it's `.DisplayName` property.

So you should change your checking to:

```
foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll())
{
    if (result != null && result.DisplayName != null)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(result.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user541597: well - is the `comboBox2` even created at the time you run this code? Can you check when debugging whether `comboBox2` or `comboBox2.Items` is NULL??

Comment: Was calling the method before initializing the components.