# C# DirectorySearcher only locates users from the country where the server sits

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory

I'm using `DirectorySearcher` to try to find information about users. When I try to run it on the server (which is located in Germany), it retrieves the expected information about users in Germany but not about users from any other countries.

Here's my code:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.Filter = $"(mail={user.email})";
SearchResult sr = searcher.FindOne();
```

Has anyone seen something like this? Is it a programming error, or could it be something about the server configuration?

For what it's worth, the server is running Windows Server 2008. I access it via Windows Terminal Service. I *did* confirm that Active Directory appears to work properly on the server - when I go to Windows's Active Directory Search utility and search for the same email address, I'm able to locate the user as expected.

I'm *not* an administrator on the server (someone else administers it). With that said, if the problem's likely the server, what should I ask/tell the administrator? What kinds of things could cause that, and what kind of changes might I have to make?

Comment: Active Directory has no clue what country the server is running on (it most likely doesn't even know what a country is). The problem is most likely A) you are not connecting to the correct server; or B) the user which runs that code only has permissions in the "Germany" OU

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Quick point of clarification: does that account for the fact that I can find them in Active Directory Search? Are there circumstances under which I could use the same user to find them in Active Directory Search but not find them programmatically?

Comment: The thing is that the AD GUI automatically connects to the different domains/subdomains, while that does not happen when you connect programatically

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's a very constructive piece of information - it could be very valuable. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a multi-domain environment, you have to get all the domains belonging to your forest and search them all:

```
List<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext> contexts = new List<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext>();

System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest f = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest();
foreach (System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain dom in f.Domains)
    contexts.Add(new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, dom.Name));
```

You have to search ALL of these principal contexts.

Here's an example of searching PrincipalContext object, but you'll have to do this for each one: [Getting all users from Active Directory PrincipalContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665868/getting-all-users-from-active-directory-principalcontext)