# C# DirectoryEntry find all users with a specific attribute (wWWHomePage)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryentry, directorysearcher

What would be the best way in C# to use directory entry to find all users with the attribute wWWHomePage filled in.

I am able to see if a specific user has it but I have not used Directory Entry to search all users for something like this.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, myDomain, Login.authUserName, Login.authPassword);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);
if (user != null) {
    DirectoryEntry de = (user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);
    if (de != null) {
        string whatIWant = de.Properties["wWWHomePage"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Andrew- Thanks! I have added code of what is working to get the info I need for a specific user.  I just need to check all users for this attribute.

Comment: Looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665868/getting-all-users-from-active-directory-principalcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DirectoryEntry` with `DirectorySearcher` and specify the search `Filter` to get what you want.

the `Filter` template you want is :

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(PROPERTY_NAME=SEARCH_TERM))
```

where `PROPERTY_NAME` is the property you want to search in, and `SEARCH_TERM` is the value. you could use the `*` as a wildcard search, it would give you all objects that has this property.

here is a quick example :

```
// set the properties you need.
var propertiesToLoad = new string[] { "sAMAccountName", "wWWHomePage" };

using(var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(ldap), "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(wWWHomePage=*))", propertiesToLoad))
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
    {
        if(result == null) continue;
    
        var samAccount = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0];
        
        var wWWHomePage = result.Properties["wWWHomePage"][0];
        
        // complete the code with your logic  
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `(objectClass=user)` will also get you computer object (as dumb as it sounds). If you only want user objects, you can use `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))`

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks for noting that, I've added that to the filter, hope it will be helpful. (it's been a while since I worked on AD).